# What needs to be done to get preview of TeX/LaTeX files in Preview-Pane of Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, preview

When you click on a usual text file you see its preview (contents) in the Preview Pane of the Windows Explorer. Same is possible with many other formats like Word, Excel etc.

Is it possible for TeX/LaTeX files as well? I am using TeXWorks for editing-compiling LaTeX.

Comment: That's not a tex question but a windows problem. Imho you will have to add some keys to the registry. There exist also an application called previewconfig which you can perhaps (depending on your windows version) use.